# How can I disable this preview image in start menu?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, photos

I am using Windows 10 Pro and am unable to find the settings in the Microsoft Photos App on Windows to disable this preview image in the start menu:

[image]

How can I disable this preview image in start menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the tile, more -> Disable live tile.

You may need to reboot after disabling it.

Comment: Start Menu tiles can be customized dynamically

Comment: @Ramhound I didn't get your comment.

Comment: You don’t have to reboot your system to update the layout of the Start Menu